# What happens in the background when TestNg suite xml starts running

Tags: java, testng

What happens in the background when TestNG suite XML starts running? 
Will it directly proceed with the execution of the code present under the annotations with the annotations hierarchy or will it perform some other steps before even that?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has 2 bigs steps:

1. Find tests by reading `suite.xml` and annotations
2. Run tests, in the specified order (from suite xml or annotations), in parallel or not.